# Resize a dynamically generated string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, resize

I've got an HTML page with a grid of divs containing read only text boxes, each containing a string which changes dynamically via a php script. I've been working on a javascript function to detect the string length and resize the string accordingly so that it fits cleanly in the textbox with no overflow.

This is an example of my div...

```
<a  href='http://burstu.com'>
  <div id='toprightlefthigh' class='resize'>
    <input type="text" id="toprightlefthighbox" class="idea" value="" readonly>
  </div>
</a>
```

I've tried various scripts, and my nearest fit is this one...

```
var div2length = div2.value.length;   if(div2length <=50) {
div2.value.fontSize="10px";   }
```

But no such luck.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
div2.value.fontSize="10px";
```

this doesn't work; you need to access the `fontSize` using `style`:

```
div2.style.fontSize="10px";
```

Comment: Cheers guys! :) I already tried accessing it with '.style' but that didn't work either, I guess that would suggest an error elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the fact that font-size is not inherited by a form element?

By default, browsers render most form elements (textareas, text boxes, buttons, etc) using OS controls or browser controls. So most of the font properties are taken from the theme the OS is currently using.

You'll have to target the form elements themselves if you want to change their font/text styles. In stead of targeting your wrapper div (I guess you are doing by the name you gave you're variable, div2 is not beeing set in your snippet), you should target the input directly.

@andrewGibson is also right btw, you should use the style property.

Comment: @AdamMartin121 Given this behaviour of form controls, and the fact that the input is readonly, do you really need to use it? Can you not just use a DIV? The display of form controls is more inconsistent across browsers (and harder to control) than that of simpler tags. But I suppose you may want to allow the user to copy the text, and it is less obvious that they can also do this with DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at http://fittextjs.com/ it does just that. I'm not a fan of the "throw jquery at it" crowd but that one does the job and its open source so you could have a poke around if you wanted to learn more if you are after a pure JS solution. In this case though why re-invent the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="toprightlefthighbox" class="idea" value="" />
```

Javascript:

```
var MAX_FONT = 20;
var MIN_FONT = 10;
var YOUR_STRING = "Here is my long long long long string";

var textbox = document.getElementById("toprightlefthighbox");
var fontSize = MAX_FONT + 1;
var element = document.createElement("div");

element.style.visibility = "hidden";
element.style.display = "inline-block";
element.style.padding = "0px";
element.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
element.innerHTML = YOUR_STRING;
document.body.appendChild(element);

do 
{
    fontSize -= 1; //maybe -= 0.5 in some browsers? Just change the +1 above too
    element.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
} while (fontSize > MIN_FONT && element.clientWidth > textbox.clientWidth);

document.body.removeChild(element);
element = null;

textbox.value = YOUR_STRING;
textbox.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
```

With CSS:

```
#toprightlefthighbox { width: 205px; height: 25px; font-family: arial; }
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hkN35/4/

Notice that when you decrease the width of the textbox to 200px it will bump the font size down.